# Comparing column values of Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to compare a particular column value with rest of the same column values within the same dataframe?

e.g- let a dataframe is df.

```
df= A  B
    1  1
    2  0
    1  0
    1  1
    2  0
```

So we have to first take column A, then pick one by one value and compare rest of the A value. Like, I take 1 and compare with rest of the value like [2,1,1,2] and I found 3rd and 4th value is same. So the result should give me for 1 is =

```
A
false
true
true
false
```

Now pick 2 as it is second element. Output of it will be

```
A
false
false
false
true
```

basically compare each element with all other elements

This same process will go for column `B,C,D....`

Would anyone give me any solution how to do it?

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension with compare all values without actual, which is removed by `drop`:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df.drop(i) == x for i, x in enumerate(df.values)], keys=df.index)
print (df1)
         A      B
0 1  False  False
  2   True  False
  3   True   True
  4  False  False
1 0  False  False
  2  False   True
  3  False  False
  4   True   True
2 0   True  False
  1  False   True
  3   True  False
  4  False   True
3 0   True   True
  1  False  False
  2   True  False
  4  False  False
4 0  False  False
  1   True   True
  2  False   True
  3  False  False
```

Detail:

In list comprehesnion create list of DataFrames:

```
print ([df.drop(i) == x for i, x in enumerate(df.values)])
[       A      B
1  False  False
2   True  False
3   True   True
4  False  False,        A      B
0  False  False
2  False   True
3  False  False
4   True   True,        A      B
0   True  False
1  False   True
3   True  False
4  False   True,        A      B
0   True   True
1  False  False
2   True  False
4  False  False,        A      B
0  False  False
1   True   True
2  False   True
3  False  False]
```

which are joined together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and parameter `keys` for `MultiIndex` if necessary, then is possible select each small DataFrame by `loc`:

```
print (df1.loc[0])
       A      B
1  False  False
2   True  False
3   True   True
4  False  False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterate all columns
for column in df.columns.tolist():
    # For the iterated column, iterate the line
    for line in range(len(df[column])):

        info = "column: " + str(column) + " - line: " + str(line)
        # Check if the cells below are equals to the iterated cell
        answer = df.loc[df.index > line,column] == df.loc[df.index == line,column].values[0]

        # Display the result
        print(info)
        print(answer)

        # Add the result in a dataframe
        for line in range(len(answer)):
            df_final = df_final.append([[
                info,
                answer.index[line],
                answer.values[line]
            ]])

# Display the resulting dataframe
df_final.columns = ["position", "index", "check"]
print(df_final)
```

Comment: does it fit to your needs ?